# How can i dynamically disable a Fluent UI button?

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

I am currently working with [Fluent UI buttons](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/button#overview).

What i need to do is to dynamically switch between the normal and disabled state of a button according to a `disabled` flag. I tried to do the following:

```
import { PrimaryButton as FluentUIButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

export class App extends React.Component {

  disabled: boolean = false;

  render() {  
    return (
       <FluentUIButton text={"Click me!"} disabled={this.disabled} />
    );
  }

  invert() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.disabled = !this.disabled;
      this.invert();
    }, 2000)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.invert();
  }

}
```

However the change of `disabled` seems to have no effect and the button does not react to che change.

How can i make the button dynamically change when `disabled` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { PrimaryButton as FluentUIButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

export class App extends React.Component {

  this.state = {disabled:false};

  render() {  
    return (
       <FluentUIButton text={"Click me!"} disabled={this.state.disabled} />
    );
  }

  invert() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.setState({disabled:true})
    }, 2000)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.invert();
  }

}
```

You are not using any state variable using state variables and set state you can do that.
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html